# Heroku runs locally but not in GitHub Actions

Tags: heroku, github-actions, heroku-cli

I'm trying to get latest build log with Heroku CLI in a GitHub Actions.

Locally what I'm doing is running `heroku builds:output -a my-app` and it works perfectly. If I look at the `.netrc` file its content is:

```
machine api.heroku.com
  login my-email@gmail.com
  password some-token
machine git.heroku.com
  login my-email@gmail.com
  password some-token
```

So I created a YAML file:

```yaml
name: Getting latest build

on: push
jobs:
  get-build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout triggering branch
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Add Heroku login credentials
        env:
          EMAIL: my-email@gmail.com
          API_KEY: ${{secrets.HEROKU_API_KEY}}
        run: |
          cat >~/.netrc <<EOF
          machine api.heroku.com
            login $EMAIL
            password $API_KEY
          machine git.heroku.com
            login $EMAIL
            password $API_KEY
          EOF
      - name: get log
        run: heroku builds:output -a my-app
```

but on GitHub I get:

```
Run heroku builds:output -a my-app
 ›   Warning: Our terms of service have changed: 
 ›   https://dashboard.heroku.com/terms-of-service
 ›   Warning: builds:output is not a heroku command.
Did you mean releases:output? [y/n]:
```

Even if when I change the YAML file to have the `API_KEY` hardcoded and not from GitHub secrets its still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're missing [Deploy to Heroku](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/deploy-to-heroku) in your steps and so some heroku commands can not be run.

Try dropping `.netrc` and setting up Deploy to Heroku action as per their docs

Alternatively try installing heroku cli in one of the steps: `npm i -g heroku`